# Installing matlab

Tags: installation, permissions, matlab

Hello I've been trying to install MATLAB 2012a on my device I followed the manual but I got stuck when the installer wanted to install the files in /usr/local/ It failed to creat a path called /usr/local/MATLAB/2012a.
I think the problem is in permissions so I want to know how can I give the installer the permission to create and install files in this directory or other directories ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should install software to `/usr/local/` as root. Open a terminal and type:

```
cd /path/to/your/matlab/install/folder
sudo ./installer
```

Where the install folder is the folder that contains the install script that you (presumably) clicked. The "installer" in the second command is the name of the install script file that was launched previously as normal user.